# Apache 2.4 multiple sites with different alias and path

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, alias, virtualhost

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 with apache 2.4.18 in my local network.

I want to have two diffrent websites, identified by a `/blah`, there for i want to work with aliases, like:

`192.168.2.134/wiki` => `/var/www/dokuwiki`

`192.168.2.134/sip` => `/var/www/rsip/public` (Laravel)

For that i have configured `/etc/apache2/sites-available/dokuwiki.conf` with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ServerName 192.168.2.134:80/wiki
    Alias /wiki /var/www/dokuwiki
    <Directory /var/www/dokuwiki>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And `/etc/apache2/sites-available/rsip.conf` with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ServerName 192.168.2.134:80/sip
    Alias /sip /var/www/rsip/public
    <Directory /var/www/rsip/public/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` there is:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options -Indexes
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have enabled the two sites and reloaded apache2.

Result of `apachectl -S` is:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 192.168.2.134 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dokuwiki.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 192.168.2.134 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dokuwiki.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 192.168.2.134 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/rsip.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Result of `apachectl -M` is:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

The problem is, the link to `192.168.2.134/wiki` works fine all the time, but the link to `192.168.2.134/sip` brings up a `404 File not found` and also maps to the wrong path, as i can see in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Wed Jul 18 22:00:16.601623 2018] [core:info] [pid 4686] [client 192.168.2.156:25896] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/sip/
```

If i try `192.168.2.134/rsip/public` it works.

I think it has to do with the sequence of virtualhosts, like seen when executing `apachectl -S`, like shown above..

then if i do `a2dissite dokuwiki.conf` and reload apache2, the link to `192.168.2.134/sip` works also fine. When i enable the `192.168.2.134/wiki` again, the `192.168.2.134/sip` again doesn't works.

Is it - in general - possible to do, what i am trying to do?!

btw: in `/var/www/rsip/public/.htaccess` is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        #Options -MultiViews -Indexes
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sip

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
#    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ dashboard/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ServerName directive should not have a /blah but only [scheme://]domain-name|ip-address[:port]. You should have something like this instead :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ServerName 192.168.2.134:80
    Alias /wiki /var/www/dokuwiki
    Alias /sip /var/www/rsip/public
    <Directory /var/www/dokuwiki>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/rsip/public/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Okay i reduced it to ip:port, reload but nevertheless a 404 and File does not exist: /var/www/sip in error.log ... does it matter to have two different conf files (rsip.conf and dokuwiki.conf) as sites-available?

Comment: yes it does. The configuration I've provided was to be put in one file and to be the only included file. It configured both alias.

Comment: Thanks a lot... it works with only one config file. Could you add this to your answer, that it is important to have only one config file?

Comment: Hi @DanielNe Would your configuration work if a user just types 192.168.2.134 into the address bar without any path behind it?

Comment: N@KelvinLowEeHahn no this wont work. I changed it, so on port 80 you will be directet to one app(192.168.2.134), and to the other app with an alias (192.168.2.134/wiki)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use 2 VirtualHosts on the same Domain (in this case the IP) with different DocumentRoot. Apache would always use only one of the multiple defined VirtualHosts.

ServerName should be only name or IP. The Port is already defined in VirtauHost *:80.

You could to use one VirtualHost for your IP with var/www as DocumentRoot.
The Alias is not needed, when both sites a placed under /var/www .
Maybe a softlink on the filesystem is better than a Alias in Apache.

Softlinks on filesystem can be made with:

```
ln -s /var/www/rsip/public /var/www/sip
```

Comment: its possible Andre Gelinas answered it. Thanks anyway!